# Neo4J with Py2neo: Unauthorized error HTTPS

Tags: python, database, docker, neo4j, py2neo

I have **Neo4J** running on a **Docker** container in which I have mapped the internal container ports 7473 and 7687 to their respective host ports 7473 and 7687, 7474 is exposed but not mapped.

The Neo4J server configuration regarding network.

```
# Bolt connector dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL 
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector. 
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true 
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors. 
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true 
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

I was able to login to Neo4J's webclient through the browser and change the default password.

Regarding the Python code here's the line where I create the client.

```
self.client = py2neo.Graph(host    =ip_address,
                           username=username,
                           password=password,
                           secure  =use_secure,
                           bolt    =use_bolt)
```

As soon as I execute a query like this one.

```
node = Node("FooBar", foo="bar")
self.client.create(node)
```

I get the following Unauthorized exception.

```
py2neo.database.status.Unauthorized: https://localhost:7473/db/data/
```

Any idea on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to call a separate authentication method provided by the library like this:

```
auth_port = str(self._PORT_HTTPS if use_secure else self._PORT_HTTP)
py2neo.authenticate(":".join([ip_address, auth_port]), username, password)
```

It took me a while to get to this because at first, I thought the authentication was done automatically in the constructor and then I wasn't able to make the authentication method run because I was using the bolt port.